# Channel frequency counter

Tags: go

I have a channel that emits events. I'd like to set up an "oscillometer" on top of this channel, i.e. some sort of a "frequency counter" that gets constantly updated (with some interval, of course, e.g. one second).

My first thought is to create a counter that will be incremented every time an event arrives on the channel and then have a ticker that every second prints out this counter and resets it to 0. It looks like the most straightforward approach, but I'm wondering if, maybe, there are some built-in tools for this in Go? Or maybe some libraries that can do it for me (I've tried finding one, but haven't succeeded)?

Comment: There are no tools for this, because channel sends and receives are synchronized by the channel, so a separate counter cannot be accurate. In the most common case of unbuffered channel, there is no time where a value is "in" the channel. If you are only trying to gather statistics, setup a counter yourself when you send and receive values.